# Is it possible to apply any themes to improve the appearance of Evolution?

Tags: evolution, themes

Is it possible to apply any themes to improve the appearance of Evolution?

If so, how? I think the progress of Unity makes Evolution look a bit dull, and would like to spark it up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Evolution uses the same theme as your other desktop applications but it will probably look as dull as it is now. So you are out of luck there.

To make this worthy answering I can advise on some cool themes made for Ubuntu 11.04 that also adjust evolution. This will install 3 themes:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-equinox equinox-theme
sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme
```

named Equinox Evolution Dawn, Equinox Evolution Dusk and Equinox Evolution Midnight and a Faenza icon set that go with it.

Default Ambiance:
[image: default]

Midnight:
[image: im2]

Dusk:
[image: im3]

(dawn is another light version of this)

But basically it is the same layout with the same icon set and another color.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind
Although it would be ideal if we had a variety of themes for Evolution, this is still good. How do you all come up with codes and stuff like this?

Comment: @Rinzwind
Could you please tell me how I install this?

Comment: See the beginning of the answer. There are 4 lines you need to execute in a terminal.